# "absolute" covers Shadow

Tags: html, css

I have an image in the center with a twitter feed aligned to the right of that.
I have a popup form that darkens the background with this:

```
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 5000px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
```

The only way I can get both of the div on the same level is by using "absolute".

However, the element with the "absolute" isn't darkened by the shadow.

I've rewritten this probably a dozen times so sorry if it's not useful.

```
.twitter-timeline {
  position: absolute; 
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.twitter {
  margin-right: 2%;
}
```

html

```
<div align="right" id="twitter">
   <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="280" href="<twitter link>">custom name</a> 
   <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8">
   </script>
</div>

<div class="wrapper fade-in">
   <img src="image.png" height="350" alt="alt" style="position: absolute;top: 33%"/>
</div>
```

EDIT: I'm trying to avoid using absolute position because the fade in animation won't work if it's absolute, plus it screws with the shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.twitter-timeline {
 position: absolute; 
 right: 0;
 margin-right: 2%;
 z-index: -999;
}
```

Comment: No dice. I was messing with z-index for a bit but I never got it to work.

It doesn't seem to do anything for me. The twitter is in the right spot but the image goes to where it's supposed to be for a split second then drops down.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!